# Magento 2 Reindex by Website or Store id

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexer

Is there any possibility to run Magento 2 indexer based on Website id. I have tried identifying events for indexer but couldn't find one.

Is there any option to validate website id or run indexer for particular store. I'm also considering custom CLI command to run indexing based on website id not sure if it is right approach. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom indexer to do indexing on the basis of website & store id.

Reference link -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexing-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in native Magento.

The only reason I saw so far was because of parallelization - it is possible to set "indexer dimensions" so that price indexing tables are written by customer group or **per website.**

More details in
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Indexers-parallelization-and-optimization/ba-p/104922

What specific business requirement are we trying to solve here?

Comment: We  are having around 30+ stores in our Magento 2 application, When importing products, We are facing issue, as indexing is happening for all store(s). So We are checking possible way to index particular store, where import is being done